# install from fork requirements not from source requirements

Tags: composer-php, gist

the source has a requirement as follows

```
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.2",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "~2.1",
    "cboden/Ratchet": "0.2.*"
},
```

in my fork it is like this 
`"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.2",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "~2.1",
        "cboden/Ratchet": "0.3.*"
    },`

When I install from my fork with composer , it always says that it requires cboden/Ratchet": "0.2.* , but I want to work with cboden/Ratchet": "0.3.*

can you help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `symfony/framework-bundle` effectively requires all Symfony components to be of version 2.1, I have bad news for you: `cboden/ratchet` version 0.3 requires some Symfony components of version 2.2.

You have to upgrade the Symfony version you are using to make it work.

Comment: I have symfony 2.4 , is that ok ?